# What's going on inside of this recursive function?

Tags: java, recursion

I have this recursive factorial function:

```
public class Driver{
public static void main (String args[])
{

    System.out.println(factorial(5));

}

private static int factorial(int n)
{
    int product;
    if (n <= 2){ product = n; return 2;}
    else{
        product = n * factorial(n-1);
        System.out.println("current product =" + product);
        System.out.println("product = " + n + " * factorial(" + (n-1) + ")");
    }
    return product;
}
}
```

It prints the following:

```
current product =6
product = 3 * factorial(2)
current product =24
product = 4 * factorial(3)
current product =120
product = 5 * factorial(4)
120
```

I'm trying to figure out what the heck is going on here. I don't understand how it starts printing for n = 2. And where did current product = 6 come from? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`n==2` is your base case, so the first function to get past the below line is the one where `n-1 == 2` or `n == 3`. This is because your output is performed after the recursive call, so it prints the deepest call first (thanks Patricia Shanahan) . If you want it to print from big to small, move your `println` lines above the line which calls `factorial` recursively.

```
product = n * factorial(n-1);
```

**Also**,

```
if (n <= 2){ product = n; return 2;}
```

This is wrong for so many reasons..

It should be

```
if (n <= 1){ return 1;}
```

If you are having trouble understanding this, remember that **each call of factorial is independent of other calls**.

Comment: Note that the output is done after the recursive call, so the first two lines are from the deepest activation that does output.

Comment: ohh crapy yeah I see the error now thank you. Can you explain a bit more about what you mean by "to get past the below line". Thanks!

Comment: @papercuts if you can, try to run through it in the debugger, that might help better than I can.

Comment: @KarthikT could you tell me how to do this in eclipse? I really appreciate the help btw.

Comment: @papercuts Double click on the grey area to the left of a line to set a "breakpoint". Now set a break point at the original call to factorial, and run  the application with "Debug as" or the bug icon to the left of the green arrow "Run" icon. You can  explore beyond this. You should use "Step into" or "Step over" to run your code one at a time. They are present in the debug perspective, which you should automatically switch to.